# How to write XmlType for node names of classes that inherit from a base class using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I would like to generate the following XML from a group of C# objects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyRoot xmlns="http://sample.com">
  <Things>
    <This>
      <ThisRef>this ref</ThisRef>
    </This>
    <That>
      <ThatRef>that ref</ThatRef>
    </That>
  </Things>
</MyRoot>
```

Unfortunately, the XML Node **Things** can contain several **This** or **That** nodes, and I don't have any control over the XML Schema.  I need to create C# objects that will write the proper XML but I'm having trouble with the **Things** collection.

Here's what I have so far:

```
[XmlRoot("MyRoot", Namespace = XmlNamespace)]
public class MyRoot
{
    public const string XmlNamespace = "http://sample.com";
    public List<MyThing> Things { get; set; }

}
[XmlInclude(typeof(This))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(That))]
public class MyThing
{
}
[XmlRoot(Namespace = MyRoot.XmlNamespace)]
[XmlType("This")]
public class This : MyThing
{
    public string ThisRef { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot(Namespace = MyRoot.XmlNamespace)]
[XmlType("That")]
public class That : MyThing
{
    public string ThatRef { get; set; }
}
[TestClass]
public class so
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SerializeTest()
    {
        // Create object to serialize
        var data = new MyRoot { Things = new List<MyThing>() };
        data.Things.Add(new This { ThisRef = "this ref" });
        data.Things.Add(new That { ThatRef = "that ref" });

        // Create XML namespace
        var xmlNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        xmlNamespaces.Add(string.Empty, MyRoot.XmlNamespace);

        // Write XML
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRoot));
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, data, xmlNamespaces);
            var xml = writer.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(xml);
        }
    }
}
```

Generates the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyRoot xmlns="http://sample.com">
  <Things>
    <MyThing d3p1:type="This" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ThisRef>this ref</ThisRef>
    </MyThing>
    <MyThing d3p1:type="That" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ThatRef>that ref</ThatRef>
    </MyThing>
  </Things>
</MyRoot>
```

So, I have two questions:

1. How can I get the XmlSerializer to write **This** and **That** nodes instead of **MyThing** nodes?
2. How can I stop the XmlSerializer from adding additional namespace information to the **This** and **That** nodes (currently written as **MyThing** nodes)?

Comment: It can't.  Instead the serializer creates 'type' attributes with values "this" and "that".  You would have to write your own serializer.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your comment, but I was able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it about posting to stackoverflow that immediately leads you to the answer?  I simply needed to do the following:

```
[XmlRoot("MyRoot", Namespace = XmlNamespace)]
public class MyRoot
{
    public const string XmlNamespace = "http://sample.com";
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(This))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(That))]
    public List<MyThing> Things { get; set; }
}
public class MyThing
{
}
public class This : MyThing
{
    public string ThisRef { get; set; }
}
public class That : MyThing
{
    public string ThatRef { get; set; }
}
```